# how to use StanfordParser on Heroku with Python?

Tags: python, heroku, cloud9

I'm trying to use Stanford Parser on Heroku with Python.
But I get this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nltk/parse/stanford.py", line 150, in raw_parse_sents
    return self._parse_trees_output(self._execute(cmd, '\n'.join(sentences), verbose))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nltk/parse/stanford.py", line 216, in _execute
    stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nltk/internals.py", line 134, in java
    raise OSError('Java command failed : ' + str(cmd))
OSError: Java command failed : ['/usr/bin/java', '-mx1000m', '-cp', 'stanford-parser-3.4.1-models.jar', 'edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser', '-model', 'edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz', '-sentences', 'newline', '-outputFormat', 'penn', '-encoding', 'utf8', '/var/folders/vy/rll459h54ts7pt6l0hs62nth0000gr/T/tmpffdpj0v5']
```

Is there anyone who has any idea on how to solve this?
I think it's a problem with Heroku because this works in my local environment on cloud9.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was incompatibility of heroku and GitLFS.
GitLFS is unsupported in heroku.
And that made the jar file unable to be opened from source code.